# ngRoute not connecting well with my index.html file

Tags: angularjs

Ok now i dont undestand the concept here. When i delete everything from registratoin.html, nothing actually happens to the result?  Where is the #/ Going to? Im confused...

Here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.6.2/firebase-simple-login.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.1.3/angularfire.js"></script>
    <script src = "http://s.codepen.io/assets/libs/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="X-UA-Compatible" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <title>Login - UniqueCoders</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="LoginApp">
    <div id="page">
        <header class="container">
        </header>
        <div ng-view>
        <main class="container">
            <div class="row login">

                <form ng-controller="AuthCtrl">
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model = "email" id="email">
                    <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="Password" id="password">
                    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" ng-click="createUser()">
                </form>
                <a href = "#/logIn">Want to Log In?</a>
            </div>
        </main>
        </div>
        <footer class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <small>&copy; 2016. Unique Coders</small>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is my script.js:

```
var app = angular.module('LoginApp', ["firebase", "ngRoute"])

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'registration.html',
        controller: 'AuthCtrl'
      })
      .when('/logIn', {
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });


  });


app.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth",
  function($firebaseAuth) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://uniquecoders.firebaseio.com/");
    return $firebaseAuth(ref);
  }
]);


app.controller("AuthCtrl", ["$scope", "Auth",
  function($scope, Auth) {
    $scope.createUser = function() {
      $scope.message = null;
      $scope.error = null;


      Auth.$createUser({
        email: $scope.email,
        password: $scope.password
      }).then(function(userData) {
        $scope.message = "User created with uid: " + userData.uid;
      }).catch(function(error) {
            $scope.error = error;
            if(error = 'INVALID_EMAIL'){
              alert("The Email you entered is Invalid")
            }
            else if(error = "INVALID_PASSWORD"){
              alert("The Password you entered is Invalid")
            }
            else if(error = "EMAIL_TAKEN"){
              console.log("The Email you entered is taken. Please Log In")
            }
            else{
              alert(error)
            }
      });
    };

  /*  $scope.removeUser = function() {
      $scope.message = null;
      $scope.error = null;

      Auth.$removeUser({
        email: $scope.email,
        password: $scope.password
      }).then(function() {
        $scope.message = "User removed";
      }).catch(function(error) {
        $scope.error = error;
      });
    };*/
  }
]);
```

And here is my registration.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/simple-login/1.6.2/firebase-simple-login.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.1.3/angularfire.js"></script>
    <script src = "http://s.codepen.io/assets/libs/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="X-UA-Compatible" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <title>Login - UniqueCoders</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body >
    <div id="page">
        <header class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-UXr_le-DEc4/VogTLE2yDfI/AAAAAAAAAfI/9RycRDVGNu8/w993-h207-no/uniquecoders.png" alt="UniqueCoders">
            </div>
        </header>

        <main class="container">
            <div class="row login">

                <form >
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model = "email" id="email">
                    <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="Password" id="password">
                    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" ng-click="createUser()">
                </form>
                <a href = "#/logIn">Want to Log In?</a>
            </div>
        </main>
        </div>
        <footer class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <small>&copy; 2016. Unique Coders</small>
            </div>
        </footer>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A 404 when retrieving your index file (which I'm assuming is the entrance point to your angular app) has nothing to do with angular whatsoever, but rather server-side routing.  This isn't an angular issue.

Comment: ? Umm Confused lol @DavidL

Comment: this doesn't make sense.  you can't use the index.html file that contains the `<ng-view>` as the template that will be *inserted into* the `<ng-view>`....

Comment: So how do i exactly fix it @Claies? I like am good at learning from examples.

Comment: aside from that, you have enabled html5mode, which requires additional server side configuration.

Comment: @Claies im confused. Can you anwser the question if you can or want to. It would be really helpfull to me. Thankyou

Comment: you should start with reading the [official documentation for `ng-view`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView).  You aren't using it correctly here and the documentation explains the correct way to use it much better than I ever could.

Comment: ? Um @Claies can i edit the code if i get more problems and you can help me? Cause im 99.99 % sure after reading that doc i will still be stuck..

Comment: I dont understand this @Claies?   
this doesn't make sense. you can't use the index.html file that contains the <ng-view> as the template that will be inserted into the <ng-view>..

Comment: When i take the locationprovider out like when i prieview it , it crashes. Can you please explain @Claies. Thankyou sir for your time

Comment: `ng-view` is **replaced** by the `template` that you are using.  You tried to make index.html your `template`, which won't work because it can't be inserted into itself.

Comment: Im still confused after docs and your example. Your trying to tell me to not use ng-view? Im confused @Claies

Comment: no, I'm not saying to not use `ng-view` at all.  what I am saying is, ***you cannot insert `index.html`*** **into** ***`index.html`***

Comment: make your `templateUrl` some other file other than `index.html`.

Comment: Wow i just understood. @Claies ima check it out. If it works.. Your the man!

Comment: Ok @Claies it worked but i still dont understand a concept. Ima edit the question so you see what im not clear on. Would love it if you can anwser question

Comment: I edited question @Claies

Comment: this is a direct copy of the example code from the documentation.  http://plnkr.co/edit/Pp3p2kea9DDPBDfnOI6o?p=preview.  study the index page, notice what is in the `<div ng-view>` and what is not.  study what is in each of the template pages, and what is not.  then try to make your code match the documentation example.

Comment: Thank you soo much @Claies. You dont understand how much you helped me!